# Getting Uncaught Error on Vivus.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vivus

I get this error in the console when I navigate to another page on my site

> "Uncaught Error: Vivus [constructor]: "element" parameter is not
>   related to an existing ID(…)"

I have this code under the jQuery ready document

```
var builtSwirl = new Vivus('built-left-swirl', { type:'delayed',
start: 'manual', duration: 400, pathTimingFunction: Vivus.EASE });
```

*'built-left-swirl' id is only in the homepage not on other pages*

I use Vivus on my homepage but not on the other pages, how can I set it to only look for the id on the homepage?

Comment: Put some code please

Comment: Hi, sorry, I put in some code